# Преобразование из Entity в Dto

Tags: java, entity-framework, java-stream, dto

Мне нужно из листа получить мапу с помощью стрима.

У меня метод который должный все это сделать, он принимает 2 параметра List

```
  protected <T,R> Map<Integer, List<R>> mapToMap(Collection<T> values, Function<T, R> mapper)  {



}
```

Первый параметр value это лист объектов в которых есть некоторые поля и id.

Второй параметр это обычный метод map, который принимает Entity и возвращает Dto

Что в итоге получается, в DTO нет поля id, но оно есть у Entity. Мне нужно сделать `Map<Integer, List<DTO>>`(ключ для мапы мы должны взять из Entity, он там хранится полем) из `List<Entity>`(вместо Entity другой класс)

Пока что я дошел только до того, что могу из Entity достать ключ и сделать мапу

```
values.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Entity::getId))
```

но дальше я не понимаю, как мне размапить поля в Entity. Основная задача сделать мапинг из Entityt в Dto

Answer (score 0):

В данном методе следует "типизировать" `T`, так как не всякий тип `T` имеет метод `getId`.

Затем в `Collectors.groupingBy` использовать дополнительно `Collectors.mapping`, вызвать метод `apply` в маппере и собрать DTO в список:

```java
protected <T extends Entity, R> Map<Integer, List<R>> mapToMap(
    Collection<T> values, Function<T, R> mapper
)  {
    return values.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                    Entity::getId, 
                    Collectors.mapping(mapper::apply, Collectors.toList())
            ));
}
```

---

Также можно дополнительно указать тип идентификатора как дженерик, соответственно, его нужно будет указать в `Entity`:

```java
public interface Entity<T> {
    T getId();
}

// ....
protected <T extends Entity<K>, K, R> Map<K, List<R>> mapToMap(
    Collection<T> values, Function<T, R> mapper
)  {
    return values.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                Entity::getId,
                Collectors.mapping(mapper::apply, Collectors.toList())
            ));
}
```

Если используется Spring JPA, то в качестве `Entity` можно взять интерфейс [`Persistable<ID>`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/Persistable.html).